# Instancing with a dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, client-server, instance, instantiation

I am currently working on a project which creates a dictionary with an int index of the instance and a complex type as the value. Since this is a huge school project I do not want to post a ton of code as I have a logic problem rather than a "I need code". I'll try to be as clear as I can and if there is something I need to explain better please let me know.

First off. I have a dictionary in my server:

```
private Dictionary<int,List<complexType>> dictName = new  Dictionary<int,List<complexType>>
```

Every time a client starts up it registers with the dictionary (i create a blank complex type to instantiate it then i load the dictionary):

```
List<complexType> temp = null;
dictName.Add(id,temp)
```

Then when the time comes that I want to add to the list for a particular instance I do this:

```
complexType myItem = new complexType();
dictName[id].Add(myItem);
```

When I run this code I get an error when a second client tries to run:

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation.

Now this happens when the second user hits:
`dictName.Add(id,temp)` from the first part.

If i change the instantiation of temp to `List<complexType> temp = new List<complexType>();`

then it passes that spot but I get the same error again  when it updates the clients.

I am currently using this way of passing data with int and string (dictionary)
and they work fine but when I added in a List of a complex type in the dictionary I got the above error.

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it. I'm hoping it has something to do with my initial load of a blank list. If there is anything else you need to know please Ask Thanks!

Comment: What's the exception? The posted exception *should* have an InnerException property. Can you tell us what it is?

Comment: @spender I looked and it doesnt seem to have one...when i debug through it just randomly throws the break statement with the exception I showed above. It then opens up a tab saying no source avalible. I also tried putting in a try catch to get information but it doesnt enter the catch

Comment: Are you trying to access it from different threads?

Comment: "new private ... ()"?! I hope its just a mistake here.

Comment: Define "when the second user hits"

Comment: @YoryeNathan yes that was a typeo thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Blam When the second user starts an instance (runs the client and registers with the server)

Comment: Show this code and indicate which line throws the exception  "List<complexType> temp = new List<complexType>();
then it passes that spot but I get the same error again when it updates the clients."   "List<complexType> temp = null;" does NOT instantiate - new is required to instantiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a dictionary of lists.  So you were trying to add to a list that was null and that is what gave you the first exception.

Second, I've never seen the "new private Dictionary" is this a cut and paste typo?

This works:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictName = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dictName.Add(0, new List<string>());
dictName[0].Add("First");
dictName.Add(1, new List<string>());
dictName[1].Add("Second");
```

The fact that you have list of a complex type and I have list of strings shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should initialize the dictionary entry as:

```
dictName.Add(id, new List<complexType>());
```

You can also try using the generic Lookup type, which is basically exactly what you need - key to a list of values.

```
var lookupName = new Lookup<int, complexType>();

lookup.Add(id, new complexType()); // Creates key 'id' and adds new ct.
lookup.Add(id, new complexType()); // Adds new ct to existing key 'id'
lookup.Add(651, null); // Creates key 651 and adds null
```

So you can just use the add method to add complex type instances to an id key without even thinking of whether the key exists or not.

```
lookup[id]
```

Will return you an IEnumerable of the complex types linked to the given id.

Example:

```
var lu = new Lookup<int, string>();

lu.Add(7, "Seven");
lu.Add(7, "SEVEN");
lu.Add(4, "Four");
lu.Add(7, "7");
lu.Add(4, "FOUR");
lu.Add(4, "FOUR");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lu[7])); // "Seven, SEVEN, 7"
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lu[4])); // "Four, FOUR, FOUR"

foreach (var grp in lu)
{
    int id = grp.Key;

    foreach (var str in grp)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I change the instatiation but when i do the "dictName[id].Add(myItem)" I want to add to the list for that id, not make a new list everytime unless i am misinterperting your code.

Comment: Lookup has a list for each key, and when you use the add method as I showed, it creates a new key and list if the key does not exist, and adds to the existing list if it does. Try it out.

Comment: @user1219627 I added another example for how to use Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictName = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
 dictName.Add(0, null);
 dictName[0] = new List<string>();
 dictName[0].Add("Hello");
```